# Problem of assigning some values to a set from multiple options algo

Tags: algorithm, set

I have a problem statemment, where I have some sets and each set have some options, some specific option from options, needs to be assigned to that set.

Some options can be common in multiple sets, but none can be assigned to more than one set. Need an algo to achieve this. A rough example is

Set1 has options [100,101,102,103] - 2 needs to be selected, 
Set2 has options [101,102,103,104] - 2 needs to be selected, 
Set3 has options [99,100,101] - 2 needs to be selected,

so the possible solution is 
Set1 gets 100,102
Set2 gets 103,104
Set3 gets 99,101

Can anyone suggests an approach on how can I get a generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be modelled as an instance of the [bipartite graph matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

Let `A` be the numbers which appear in the lists (combined into one set with no duplicates), and let `B` be the lists themselves, each repeated according to how many elements need to be selected from them. There is an edge from a number `a ∈ A` to a list `b ∈ B` whenever the number `a` is in the list `b`.

Therefore this problem can be approached using an algorithm which finds a "perfect matching", i.e. a matching which includes all vertices. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching) lists several algorithms which can be used to find matchings as large as possible, including the [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) and the [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: Repeating the sets according to the number needed is a nice idea. It was that particular constraint that initially led me to suspect that it was NP-hard.

Comment: Since bipartite matching can also be modelled as a graph flow problem, it is probably possible to avoid repetitions using weighted edges; the edges from `A` to `B` should all have weight 1, but the edges from `B` to the sink can be weighted according to how many elements should be selected from the list. That seems like it should be correct but it would need a proof.

Comment: I think it more natural to think of them as supply and demand and nodes rather than weights on the edges, but you are right that it can be considered a flow problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kaya3, I was not remembering the exact algo, and getting me remember that its a bipartite graph matching problem was really helpful.

But it wasn't giving me the exact solution when I needed n number of options for each So I followed the following approach, i.e.

```
A = [99,100,101,102,103,104]
B = [a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2]
# I repeated the instances because I need 2 instances for each and created my   
# graph like this
# Now my graph will be like
99  => [c1, c2]
100 => [a1, a2, c1, c2]
101 => [a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2]
102 => [a1, a2, b1, b2]
103 => [a1, a2, b1, b2]
104 => [b1, b2]
```

Now it is giving correct solution everytime. I tried with multiple use cases. Repeating

Comment: I was working on a rails project where I got this problem, so created a gem for this problem. Hope it will be helpful for others https://github.com/raghvendra1501/bipartite_graph_sets